# Query Builder With Join CodeIgniter, return 1 row

Tags: php, codeigniter, query-builder

hello guys i need help understanding CodeIgniter, im new in framework
i have this query builder inside a function

```
public function findLeader($where)
  {
    $this->db->select('me.EMP_FULL_NAME');
    $this->db->from('tr_approval ta');
    $this->db->join('m_employee me', 'me.EMP_ID = ta.EMP_ID'); 
    $this->db->where($where);
    //$namaLeader = $this->db->count_all_results();
    $name = $this->db->get();
    $name->row_array();
    $name = $name['EMP_FULL_NAME'];
    return $name;
  }
```

and this code for call the function

```
$where = array(
         'ta.RB_ID' => 'RB/210113/0001', 
         'ta.TR_APP_STATUS' => '0', 
         );
$getName = $this->Model_online->findLeader($where);
echo $getName;
```

but i got this error

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Cannot use object of type CI_DB_mysqli_result as array

Filename: C:\laragon\www\onlineform\application\models\Model_online.php

Line Number: 38
```

pls help, im trying get only 1 row from the query builder but i cant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `$name` is initially object and `row_array()` is used to retrieve single row as array form you have to save it in a `$variable`. You have to reassign the value of `$name`:

```
$name = $this->db->get();
$name = $name->row_array();
$name = isset($name['EMP_FULL_NAME']) ? $name['EMP_FULL_NAME'] : 'Not Available';
```

or use this method:

```
 $name = $this->db->get()->row_array();

 $name = isset($name['EMP_FULL_NAME']) ? $name['EMP_FULL_NAME'] : 'Not Available';
```

Comment: hello sir thank you for answering me, but i still get this error
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Filename: models/Model_online.php

Line Number: 37

Comment: the thing is if i using this method, i can return it with no errror. but only count the row $this->db->count_all_results();

Comment: the is because maybe your query finding nothing or your data doesnot have EMP_FULL_NAME offset see my updated answer

Comment: i got error from my own logic sir, because i loop that call function and there is a data that  'ta.TR_APP_STATUS' => other than 0, thats why it become error when looping on that data